# EntityManager not injected using @PersistenceContext in EJB-JAR [JBOSS 7, Seam 2]

Tags: jpa, jboss, jboss7.x, seam, entitymanager

I have an EAR file which defines EJB-JAR, WAR and bunch of other JAR files. I have an `ejb-jar-1.jar` which defines EJBs, Services and Entities. It also defines `persistence.xml` in the `META-INF` folder. In the `app-war.war` I define `components.xml` which declares `persistence:entity-manager-factor` and `persistence:mananged-persistence-context` elements. Now, in one of my services in the `ejb-jar-1.jar` uses `@PersistenceContext` annotation for injecting an `EntityManager`. But when the code is run the `EntityManager` in that service is always `NULL`. I'm not sure what's happening. And it is only the `EntityManager` that it is not able to inject all other injections work properly. Project structure is below.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Pointers would be helpful as well. I'm upgrading project to run on JBOSS 7.1.1.Final.

Deployement Info

```
* JBOSS 7.1.1.FINAL
* Uses seam framework: jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar
* Uses Hibernate 3.4.0.GA
```

main-ear.ear

```
|__META-INF
|   |____jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|   |____application.xml
|   |____jboss-app.xml
|   |____MANIFEST.MF
|__lib
|   |____somejar.jar
|   |____somejar.jar
|__ejb-jar-1.jar
|   |____META-INF
|        |____persistence.xml
|__ejb-jar-2.jar
|__jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar
|__commons-lang-2.4.jar
|__commons-codec-1.1.jar
|__jasypt-1.6.jar
|__app-war.war
    |____components.xml
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
            <module name="org.picketlink" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.picketbox" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.dom4j" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="1" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="app-war.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.ejb-jar-1.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.ejb-jar-2.jar" />
            <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.jasypt-1.6.jar" />
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.commons-codec-1.1.jar" />
    <module name="deployment.main-ear.ear.commons-lang-2.4.jar" />
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">
    <description>myapp</description>
    <display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb-jar-1.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>ejb-jar-2.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>jboss-seam-2.2.1.CR2.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>app-war.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/app</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

components.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components ...>
    <core:init debug="@debug@" jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@" security-enabled="@seamSecurity@" precedence="30" />
    <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory" persistence-unit-name="coreUnit" precedence="30"/>
    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" precedence="30"/>
    <security:persistent-permission-resolver permission-store="#{cacheEnabledJpaPermissionStore}" />
    <transaction:ejb-transaction precedence="30"/>
    ...
</components>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending three weeks on this problem I finally found the answer. And the answer simply is Container Managed Persistence in `JBOSS 7.1.1.Final` for the above project structure i.e. EAR and technologies is broken. It may be working for a WAR I'm not sure. But it doesn't work for an EAR based project.

Upgrade to `EAP 6.1.0.Final`+ and it will work.

The difference in the 2 builds is that persistence.xml is read at the beginning by the container in the `EAP 6.1.0` build but `7.1.1.Final` never attempts to read `persistence.xml` and hence never creates an `EntityManagerFactory`.

Hope this would help others.

Comment: you did ask them at https://community.jboss.org/thread/232590 too